# Why the values from Hadoop API doesn't match with the calculated values?

Tags: hadoop, high-availability, capacity, namenode

```json
 {
    "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=FSNamesystem",
    "modelerType" : "FSNamesystem",
    "tag.Context" : "dfs",
    "tag.HAState" : "active",
    "CapacityTotal" : 250375106560,
    "CapacityTotalGB" : 233.0,
    "CapacityUsed" : 1316515840,
    "CapacityUsedGB" : 1.0,
    "CapacityRemaining" : 171912445952,
    "ProvidedCapacityTotal" : 0,
    "CapacityRemainingGB" : 160.0,
    "CapacityUsedNonDFS" : 64353255424
}
```

I am using the formula to find the `CapacityTotal`:

```
CapacityTotal = CapacityUsed + CapacityRemaining + CapacityUsedNonDFS
```

Here, the `CapacityTotal` value obtained using the formula doesn't match with the one given by default from the Hadoop API. Similar is the case for different parameters namely, `memoryused` etc.

Why is there a mismatch in the values obtained from the Hadoop API? How could I resolve this issue?